# iOS unable to hide toolbar UIbarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am unable to find the way to hide a UIbarButtonItem set on a toolbar. The button is properly declared and linked on IB. However the following line does nothing,

```
self.botoVolver = nil;
```

Comment: I had similar issue. Got is resolved using this 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10747999/1753005

Answer (score -1):

Just reset the button on the toolbar, try this:

```
[self.toolbar setItems:nil];
```

Comment: why not just `[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:nil animated:NO];`  ?