# Make a UIBarButtonItem disappear using swift IOS

Tags: swift, conditional-statements, uibarbuttonitem, iboutlet

I have an IBOutlet that I have linked to from the storyboard

```
@IBOutlet var creeLigueBouton: UIBarButtonItem!
```

and I want to make it disappear if a condition is true

```
if(condition == true)
{
    // Make it disappear
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Do you really want to hide/show `creeLigueBouton`? It is instead much easier to enable/disable your UIBarButtonItems. You would do this with a few lines:

```
if(condition == true) {
    creeLigueBouton.enabled = false
} else {
    creeLigueBouton.enabled = true
}
```

This code can even be rewritten in a shorter way:

```
creeLigueBouton.enabled = !creeLigueBouton.enabled
```

Let's see it in a UIViewController subclass:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var creeLigueBouton: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBAction func hide(sender: AnyObject) {
        creeLigueBouton.enabled = !creeLigueBouton.enabled
    }

}
```

---

If you really want to show/hide `creeLigueBouton`, you can use the following code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var condition: Bool = true
    var creeLigueBouton: UIBarButtonItem! //Don't create an IBOutlet

    @IBAction func hide(sender: AnyObject) {
        if(condition == true) {
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = []
            condition = false
        } else {
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [creeLigueBouton]
            condition = true
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        creeLigueBouton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Creer", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "creerButtonMethod")
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [creeLigueBouton]
    }

    func creerButtonMethod() {
        print("Bonjour")
    }

}
```

Comment: And for a disabled button is it possible to modify the text color?

Comment: was looking for a long time, this is the perfect answer till now.

Comment: As of iOS 16, UIBarButtonItem has its own `isHidden` property so none of this is necessary. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77661479/20287183).

Answer (score 53):

Use the property enabled and tintColor

```
    let barButtonItem:UIBarButtonItem? = nil

    if isHidden{
        barButtonItem?.enabled      = false
        barButtonItem?.tintColor    = UIColor.clearColor()
    }else{
        barButtonItem?.enabled      = true
        barButtonItem?.tintColor    = nil
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, mate! Worked for me.

Comment: Awesome! Works well

Comment: As of iOS 16, UIBarButtonItem has its own `isHidden` property so none of this is necessary. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77661479/20287183).

Answer (score 14):

```
// Nice answer haiLong, I think as an extension this is more convenient.

extension UIBarButtonItem {
    var isHidden: Bool {
        get {
            return !isEnabled && tintColor == .clear
        }
        set {
            tintColor = newValue ? .clear : nil
            isEnabled = !newValue
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Removed forced unwrapping and fixed enabled value.

Comment: This is great but it doesn't work if your UIBarButtonItem contains a customView, if it does you can call hidden on that view directly.

Comment: As of iOS 16.0, UIBarButtonItem has its own `isHidden` property. This extension is no longer needed.

Answer (score 13):

**For Swift 3**

```
if (your_condition) {
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.addAsset_btn
 }
else {
  // hide your button
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

**First way:**

Just set `.title` to `""`

**Second way:**

Just call `updateToolBar()` whenever you want to show/hide the `creeLigueBouton`.

```
func updateToolBar() {
    var barItems: [UIBarButtonItem] = []

    if condition != true {
        // Make it appear
        barItems.append(creeLigueBouton)
    }

    barItems.append(anotherButton)

    myToolBar.setItems(barItems, animated: true)

    myToolBar.setNeedsLayout()
}
```

Comment: @JSA986 yeah... thats true

Comment: (second way works even if the bar button item has no title)

Comment: Second way doesn't work unless you create a strong outlet reference or instantiate your button programmatically

Answer (score 4):

The following solution works for me.

```
        var skipButton: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
    skipButton.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 58.0, 32.0);
    skipButton.setTitle("Skip", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    skipButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 122.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    skipButton.addTarget(self, action: "rightButtonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    var skipButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: skipButton)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = skipButtonItem;

    if hideSkipButton == true {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

heres my solution:

hide:

```
self.creeLigueBouton.title = ""
self.creeLigueBouton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain
self.creeLigueBouton.enabled = false
```

show:

```
self.creeLigueBouton.title = "Original Button Text"
self.creeLigueBouton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered
self.creeLigueBouton.enabled = true
```

Answer (score 3):

It is quite late to reply but looking for an answer for my problem I found this topic. The marked answer did not help me, but I managed to solve my problem thanks to @haiLong's answer. My solution works for all types of bar buttons... I think. Add this to your ViewController and use as needed.

```
var tintColorsOfBarButtons = [UIBarButtonItem: UIColor]()

    func hideUIBarButtonItem(button: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if button.tintColor != UIColor.clear {
            tintColorsOfBarButtons[button] = button.tintColor
            button.tintColor = UIColor.clear
            button.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

    func showUIBarButtonItem(button: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if tintColorsOfBarButtons[button] != nil {
            button.tintColor = tintColorsOfBarButtons[button]
        }
        button.isEnabled = true
    }
```

I hope it saves some time to other developers :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have set of `UIBarButtonItem`s to hide, e.g. only show them on Landscape orientation, and hide or Portrait, you can use tag and Swift Array's filter. Let's assume we made `@IBOutlet` link to `UIToolBar`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var toolbar: UIToolbar!
```

First, we save toolbar's items in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  toolbarItems = toolbar.items
}
```

Set the tag property of UIBarButtonItem you want to show on Landscape orientation to 1 or whatever you like. Then, override func `traitCollectionDidChange`

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

    switch (traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass, traitCollection.verticalSizeClass) {
    case (.Compact, .Regular): // iPhone Portrait
      let items: [UIBarButtonItem]?
      if view.frame.width > 320 { // iPhone 6 & 6S
        items = toolbarItems?.filter({ $0.tag < 5 })
      } else { 
        items = toolbarItems?.filter({ $0.tag < 4 })
      }
      bottomToolbar.setItems(items, animated: true)
    case (_, .Compact): // iPhone Landscape
      let items = toolbarItems?.filter({ $0.tag < 6 })
      bottomToolbar.setItems(items, animated: true)
    default: // iPad
      break
    }
  }
```

In this example, I set all `UIBarButtonItem`'s tag for iPad only to 6, iPhone Landscape to 5, and for iPhone 6 & 6+ to 4.

Answer (score 1):

I did it using this:

```
navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks for posting your solution

Answer (score 1):

I have more that 2 menuitems and remove/add menuitem is an overhead. This code snippet worked for me **(Using Swift3)**.

```
func showMenuItem(){

    menuItemQuit.customView?.isHidden = false
    menuItemQuit.plainView.isHidden = false
}

func hideMenuItem(){

    menuItemQuit.customView?.isHidden = true
    menuItemQuit.plainView.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a tool bar that I had to hide and show its last button. So I declared a var to hold the UIBarButtonItem and removed it from the bar or added depending on the situation like:

inside the class declared the var and linked the toolbar:

```
var buttonToHide : UIBarButtonItem?

@IBOutlet weak var toolbarOne: UIToolbar!
```

at the viewDidLoad :

```
buttonToHide = toolbarOne.items![toolbarOne.items!.count - 1] as? UIBarButtonItem
```

in my code I made the trick:

```
if situationOccurrsToHide {
   toolbarOne.items!.removeLast()
}
```

or

```
if situationOccursToShow 
{    
   toolbarOne.items!.append(buttonToHide!) 
}
```

You can use the removeAtIndex or insert(buttonToHide, atIndex: xx) to remove or reinsert the button at a specific position.

You must be careful not to insert or remove the button more than once.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use text attributes to hide a bar button:

```
barButton.enabled = false
barButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.clearColor()], forState: .Normal)
```

Also I've made extension for UIBarButtonItem with a hidden property:

```
extension UIBarButtonItem {

    var titleTextAttributes: [NSObject : AnyObject]! {
        set {
            setTitleTextAttributes(newValue, forState: .Normal)
        }

        get {
            return titleTextAttributesForState(.Normal)
        }

    }

    private static var savedAttributesKey = "savedAttributes"

    var savedAttributes: [NSObject : AnyObject]? {
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIBarButtonItem.savedAttributesKey, newValue, UInt(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC))
        }
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UIBarButtonItem.savedAttributesKey) as? [NSObject : AnyObject]
        }
    }

    var hidden: Bool {
        set {
            enabled = !newValue

            if newValue {
                savedAttributes = titleTextAttributes

                // Set a clear text color
                var attributes = titleTextAttributes
                attributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = UIColor.clearColor()
                titleTextAttributes = attributes
            }
            else {
                titleTextAttributes = savedAttributes
            }
        }

        get {
            return enabled
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. (Make newbackbutton global variable)

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
    let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem()

     newBackButton.title = " << Return to Gallery"
    newBackButton.style  = UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done
    newBackButton.target = self
    newBackButton.action = "backtoScoutDetail:"
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = newBackButton
```

}

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    newBackButton.title = ""
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = newBackButton        

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5:

`self.viewController?.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(nil, animated: true)`

If you're using isPreparingForSegue, you can easily adapt that so the next modal won't show like an hide button but the "back" button. :)

`segue.destination.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(nil, animated: true)`

Comment: What about this is specific to Swift 5?

Answer (score 0):

To really remove the button and reclaim the space in the bar that it used you can do it this way:

- fetch the array of left or right bar button items you want to alter
- search for the index of your button and remove it
- set the updated array to the navigationItem

This is only a quick example and does contain forced optional downcasts for simplicity - I encourage you to replace them with checks. I tested it in `viewDidLoad()` and it works for my purpose (removing items added in interface builder for some use cases).

```swift
var items = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems
items!.remove(at: items!.firstIndex(of: myUIBarButton)!)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = items
```

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 16.0 `UIBarButtonItem` has an `isHidden` property. Simply set that based on your condition:

```
if condition {
    creeLigueBouton.isHidden = true
}
```

Of course you probably want to set `isHidden` to `false` if the condition is not true. Or more simply:

```
creeLigueBouton.isHidden = condition
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Try these:

 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = ""
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = ""
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title = ""
navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true


        navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(nil, animated: true)
        navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(nil, animated: true)
```