# Hiding UIBUTTON swift

Tags: swift, uibutton

In swift, how do I hide a UIButton?

Here's what I tried: 
`button.enabled = false`

However, that just greys out the button, not making it invisible.

Is there a way to do it in swift? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: enabled is different to hidden. Enabled gives the user entitlement to use the button, hidden = false means it's visible (conversely hidden = false makes it invisible)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Umm… `button.hidden = true`. See [UIView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/hidden).

Be sure to look at methods available in parent classes when reading the documentation for a class.

---

NOTE: A later version of swift enforced `button.isHidden = true` as the only option.

Comment: For those investigating how to hide a UIBarButtonItem button, then see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492491/make-a-uibarbuttonitem-disapear-using-swift-ios

Answer (score 7):

For iOS 8+

```
button.isHidden = true
```

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622585-ishidden)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is related to your issue but just a tip for others:

If this is for the initial setup:

Make sure that you hide the button within the function ViewWillAppear(animated: Bool)

```
override func ViewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
button.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: Why not in viewDidLoad ??