# Hide or remove specific item from navigation bar button items, Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, swift4, uibarbuttonitem

Hide OR remove specific button item from navigation bar `UIBarButtonItem` which is given from storyboard.

For example right side navigation bar item I have added 3 `UIBarButtonItem` like "Done", "Cancel", "next" from storyboard and now I want to remove or Hide "Cancel" button from the navigation bar programmatically as per the user login, So what can I do for this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a UIBarButtonItem disappear using swift IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492491/make-a-uibarbuttonitem-disappear-using-swift-ios)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.remove(at: [indexOfButton])
```

[indexOfButton] should be the index of the button in the rightBarButtonItems array.