# Hide UIBarButtonItem from UINavigationBar programatically Swift2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I've tried hiding the thing, but it just appears greyed out in `UINavigationController`

I found a delete method, but it asks to pass in Anyobject..

```
Button.delete(AnyObject?)
```

Comment: Ypu want to remove the button from view. right?

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to delete it

Comment: Is it in navigation bar or normal view?

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021748/how-do-i-show-hide-a-uibarbuttonitem

Comment: @spacecash21 That's in Objc C. Both the language quite differs!

Comment: The idea is the same. @SohilR.Memon

Comment: It's in a navigation Controller

Comment: The `delete:` method you found is from the [`UIResponderStandardEditActions` informal protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/delete:) It is declared to exist on all objects, even though many don’t implement it, and isn’t at all useful for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the `UIBarButtonItem`. It's just one type of deallocating the item:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
```