# star.hidden=NO , is not working inside navigation items

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfJZc.png

Implementing buttons inside story-board.

UIviewController -> NavigationItems -> Right barButtons items -> UIView -> Buttons.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cciPS.png

I set UIButton like in image in navigation item.
I set this button hide and show according to some click.it's working fine first time, after hidden when I try to show button it's not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I show/hide a UIBarButtonItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021748/how-do-i-show-hide-a-uibarbuttonitem)

Comment: "I set this button hide and show according to some click."  Nobody sees it.

Comment: No duplication possibility, I set buttons from storyboard

Comment: show your code.

Comment: I shared second image. You may see in right side there are buttons that's I want to hide and show.